# How do I sort a spreadsheet by dates from different columns?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a a spreadsheet that contains a number of deadlines, as well as columns indicating whether the activity has been completed.  I want the sheet to sort itself by "the next due date" which will come from a different column for each row.

For example, row 3 might need to be sorted by the date in column H, whereas row 2 might need to be sorted by the date in column J (since 2's colH activity is completed).

More specifically, a row might need to be sorted by its "45N" due date; once the 45N is finished, I'd want it to be sorted by the "45R" due date.

One option I read about is to create a 'dummy' column after all the data and populate it with the "sortBy" date for each row, and then simply sort by this column (and maybe delete it afterward).  I think this would be fairly straightforward, and I have the conditional logic I'd need.

Is there a way to do this in VBA without populating a column?  Just sort of saving a variable FOR EACH ROW in VBA, rather than making it a temporary entry in the spreadsheet itself, and then performing a sort on that?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet may be to just generate a helper column with the next due dates for all rows, then sort with that

Comment: yes, you have to store the range as an array, then create that dummy column in array, sort that array by the column and then paste the results without that column, it is too much work for something simple you want to do, if you don't have many rows then simply create a dummy column and hide it, you can also write a simple event macro that sorts the range right after you change any values in the sheet such as entering a completion date for a task